# plaid + stripe ach payment integration

Tags: php, plaid

i'm integrate use plaid + stripe api to ach payment, but i can't get stripe_bank_account_token from plaid to call curl request after get account id and public_token

i'm use php here is request

```
curl https://tartan.plaid.com/exchange_token \
   -d client_id="[Plaid client ID]" \
   -d secret="[Plaid secret]" \
   -d public_token="[Plaid Link public_token]" \
   -d account_id="[Plaid Link account_id]"
```

and response is { "sandbox": true, "access_token": "test_chase" }

i can't get

```
{
  "sandbox": true,
  "access_token": "[Plaid API access token]",
  "stripe_bank_account_token": "btok_5gr1QIfvhgEKdYSr17rH",
  "account_id": "[Plaid Account ID]"
}
```

this response

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that the Client ID and Secret passed through isn't the sandbox credentials, but rather your actual client ID and secret as those are connected to your Stripe account.

Comment: This answer exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

Comment: Thank you @Charley M, yes i was sent mail to support.

Comment: I was not able to get it back on the dev mode after many tries and help from their support folks. I ended coding by experiment on the PROD mode. -not fun-

Comment: That does not work in Sandbox mode, I can't get parameter "stripe_bank_account_token" in response

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it use [this](https://support.plaid.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2522325-plaid-stripe-troubleshooting#stripe_bank_account_token_not_returned), according to the link you are missing `selectAccount` in the front-end request so that it should be like this:

```
<script>
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  env: 'sandbox',
  selectAccount: true, /* this is what i have added */
  clientName: 'Stripe/Plaid Test',
  key: '[Plaid key]',
  product: ['auth'],
  selectAccount: true,
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
    // Send the public_token and account ID to your app server.
    console.log('public_token: ' + public_token);
    console.log('account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);
  },
  onExit: function(err, metadata) {
    // The user exited the Link flow.
    if (err != null) {
      // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior to exiting.
    }
  },
});

// Trigger the Link UI
document.getElementById('linkButton').onclick = function() {
   linkHandler.open();
 };
</script>
```

in the response they return an `account_id` which will be used in the last request which does not work with you.

I hope this will help.